# ubuntu 18.04 changing uefi settings?

Tags: grub2, 18.04, uefi

After installing ubuntu 18.04 I can no longer see the uefi screen or the grub menu.  The hdmi monitor does not detect a signal until the linux boot stage.  Before installing 18.04 I could use uefi and grub.  How can I get these visible again?

Comment: I have not seen that. What brand/model system? What video card/chip? If nVidia, you may need nomodeset until you install the nVidia proprietary driver from Ubuntu repository.http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: You can use `systemctl reboot --firmware-setup` to reboot into uefi from Ubuntu. But I don't that linux is able to "hide" the option to access the uefi menu on boot